# Print jobs print locally but not through cloud print

Tags: printing, google-cloud-print

We have used Google Cloud Print Service for a few years now, very successfully. Periodically we have issues with print jobs failing, where restarting the Cloud Print Service and the Print Spooler will fix it. That is not the case today.

Today, I am able to print directly to the printer, both from my computer and from the server where we host Google Cloud Print Service. When I attempt to print from Google Cloud Print, I see the print job appear in the queue on the server, and then disappear, and in the Cloud Print queue it simply says "error" with no details on what is happening.

I restarted the print service with logging enabled, attempted to print again, and checked the debug log, with no details present. I'm stumped.

EDIT: After finding the *correct* debug log, I see this:

**CP_CONNECTOR: Job failed (spool failed)**

Has anyone dealt with this before, or know of a solution?

Things I have already tried:

- Re-connecting Cloud Print Service to our Google account
- Re sharing all printers
- Reinstalling Cloud Print Service
- Restarting the server
- Reinstalling printers

Answer (score 0):

After doing many many things, and finally getting Google support on the line, we determined it was a glitch in the Cloud Print Service. The work around, which I was unaware of, and the reason I'm posting this answer, was to use the Chrome Connector.

You can get to that by visiting chrome://devices and then sharing the printers through that form, which looks identical to the one that you get with the Cloud Print Service. I recommend clearing your printer list from Cloud Print first, so you don't get confused.

Once you've shared them, you can then share the printer through Cloud Print just as you would have before.

The only caveat, and the reason this is a work around and not a fix, is that you have to **maintain an open Chrome session**, meaning you have to keep chrome open for the printers to work. That's fine for us, as there is always a chrome tab open on the server anyway, but it may not work for you long-term.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the Beta version of chrome, and it seems to resolve the issue.  I had this issue on 3 of my 11 servers.  All where running stable versions.  It was odd that only 3 where not allowing google to print.  Once I installed the 64bit beta version, I was able to print.  As long as the server was running the Version 53, people could print.  It did not matter if someone had a version 52 on there computer.  Hope this helps.